# How to switch on sub-pixel anti-aliasing for fonts?

Tags: 11.10, fonts, antialiasing

In Fedora 16 (gnome) I did it without any problems. But in Ubuntu 11.10(gnome) in System Settings -> Appearance I can't see any tab for fonts settings.

Comment: By "gnome" you mean Gnome Shell? right?.

Comment: you can use Xfce for font-aliasing purposes, i am giving you the link http://everythingexpress.wordpress.com/2011/10/28/how-to-run-xfce-on-ubuntu-11-10-final/ Note: It is not present in ubuntu 11.10 by default

Answer (score 11):

Install `gnome-tweak-tool`  from the Software Center. Or the Terminal `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool` if you feel adventurous ;).

Open it.

Then select Font.

Anti aliasing.

[image]

It's in Spanish but you get the idea.

Comment: to install it open terminal and sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool run this command

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
```

run this command in the terminal and give the password and after installation press the super(windows) key there type "advance settings" you will find the application open it you will get the font option change it the way you like it.

further doubts
[see this.](http://www.installubuntulinux.com/2011/09/howto-change-system-font-sizes-in.html)